# Efficient way of inserting items into two tables using EF6 DbFirst

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I have two tables, eq. **Users** (UserID, CompanyID, Name, ...) and **Companies** (CompanyID, Name, ...). I have to process XML import data which generates a great number of data item into each table. In the xml file when a (new) user references into a new company - the company item must be inserted as well. When a user (or a company) item in the xml contains changed data - the items in the database must be updated.

Using EF6 creating and updating the items is quite simple - but the SubmitChanges() **takes extremely long**. I was searching the google and stackoverflow and found several similar topic - using *datacontext* and *bulk inserting* items. They are useful, but in my case when I bulk insert a new company - its ID is unknown for me, so I cannot bulk insert the user item as well. Which is the good way to solve this?

- gather all the new *company items first*, bulk insert them, read back all the
  information and ID-s? (or how would I know these new company item's ID)
- *then* bulk insert all *the user items*?

My second question: is there a common way to generate the data table structure for the bulk insert from the EF6 class? Can I write a *generic bulk insert method* using the DB First table class?

Comment: I would prefer first approach which is parsing all data locally then bulk insert. I will just feel more safer doing it that way

Comment: And which is the best way to do that? Is there any sample code for a generic bulk insert method based on a dbfirst ef6 class?

Comment: Someone did a codeplex project for efficient bulk insert in EF as it does not come with one by default. You can see the project here along with some benchmark https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Comment: It seems a useful, but a little bit undocumented and so hard-to-use lib. Firts, it says it is ef6 comaptible - but says nothing about that cannot be used with   an ObjectContext. Second, after creating a DbContext it drops an error: "BulkInsertProvider not found for 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.\nTo register new provider use EntityFramework.BulkInsert.ProviderFactory.Register() method"